# How to know what view is currently viewed

Tags: navigation, rotation

i'm working on a project in which i present a table of values, and when the user rotates the screen landscape is shows the detail as a graph.

so far it all works, but there is a problem. When I go from LandscapeLeft strait to landscapeRight for example, it pushes the view again. Obviously I don't want this to happen.

Here is the code i used:

```
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
{
    NSLog(@"Landscape Left!");
    GraphViewController *gvc = [[GraphViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GraphViewController" bundle:nil];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:gvc animated:YES];
        strg.orient = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:1];
}
if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)
{
    NSLog(@"Landscape Right!");
    GraphViewController *gvc = [[GraphViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GraphViewController" bundle:nil];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:gvc animated:YES];
        strg.orient = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:2];
}
if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait)
{
    NSLog(@"Portrate!");

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

My question is how can I know if the view is already viewed, so I can tell the NavigationController to not push it?

Thanks allot!

Comment: What language is this for? You've not specified a tag indicating that.